# couldn't play youtube.com in webview

Tags: android, webview

I was wondering why I can't play youtube.com in my WebView after I updated OS version from 2.3.6 to 4.0.3, bellow is my code

## Layout

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.55"
    android:scrollbars="none"
/>
```

## Manifest

Here I want to add "android:hardwareAccelerated="true" but doesn't allow to add this line in eclip :(

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_perry"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MeasSokSopheaActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".video" />
</application>
```

## Activity

```
public class video extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video);
    if(!haveNetworkConnection())
    {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(video.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Connection Error!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please connected to the internet in order to use this apps.");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               //here you can add functions

            } });
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    else
    {      
    mWebView = new WebView(this);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://domain/videoyoutube.php");
}
}
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient  
{  
    @Override  
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        view.loadUrl(url);  
        return true;
    }  
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    if(mWebView != null)
    {
        mWebView.destroy();
        mWebView = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
}
```

Comment: when you say can't play do you mean doesnt load? or loads and wont't play?

Comment: What doesn't work? No player, can't load video, video plays incorrectly, ??? @SeanF just beat me

Comment: Is the video you're trying to play capable of being played on mobile devices? Also, are you getting any error messages? What exactly is your issue?

Comment: Dear All, I can display http://m.youtube.com/results?q=<?=$search?> in my webview but when i click video file to view, it's doesn't load at all. **Note: $search parameter getting from videoyoutube.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube video player uses Flash, which is not supported in all devices (and most definitely not in the emulator). Therefore, your video will not load.

Alternatives:

- Try to find the video's details, and create a new `Intent` that handles the video (using `ACTION_VIEW`, I think?). Some details on doing that (and issues with it) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978963/calling-youtube-app-using-action-view-intent-failing-most-of-the-time).
- Replace the video's HTML with something using the HTML5 `<video ...>` tag, which should be supported in `WebView`. (Some limited info on that [here](http://www.youtube.com/html5)).

Comment: Dear Soxxeh, Thanks you very much for your answer. I will try with this way, But do you have any way to load android youtube application after use click the search result in my application. Ex: user search for Justin Bieber muisc in my application, then my application listed the result in my app WebView, and then when user click on the search result(Ex. Justin Bieber One Time) youtube application will launch with "Justin Bieber One Time" display in youtube application's search box.

Comment: Yup! Create a new class that extends `WebViewClient`. In it, `@Override` the method [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)). Then, check if the `String` parameter is a `YouTube` URL; if it is, load with your `Intent` and `return false`. Otherwise, `return true`. Example [here](http://lexandera.com/2009/02/intercepting-page-loads-in-webview/).

Comment: Soxxeh, I checked already, that's not what i mean. Anyway thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: No problem! You may have more luck on a new issue if you open a new question. Good luck! :)