# How to play YouTube video via Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, android-youtube-api

In my app I want to click on a particular button and jump to the youtube app and show a youtube user .Eg http://www.youtube.com/user/punjabiradiousa . How is this possible please suggest some technique?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling YouTube app using ACTION\_VIEW intent Failing most of the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978963/calling-youtube-app-using-action-view-intent-failing-most-of-the-time)

You can only view the User's profile if the YouTube app provides that feature. As for viewing Videos. You can pass video url intents. see the link

Comment: you may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16514288/1131470

Comment: I want to open it in youtube app

Comment: The title asks for video playing, question body asks for showing a user. Please edit the other to make the question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code i have used to play youtube video

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("http://www.youtube.com/embed/").matcher(mVideoId);
matcher.find()
Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(
                                null,
                                Uri.parse("ytv://" + mVideoId),
                                MainScreen.mContext,
                                com.kids.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
                                startActivity(lVideoIntent);
```

Answer (score 8):

Do it like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/user/punjabiradiousa")));
```

Taken from here: [Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)

Answer (score 0):

**Its Working**

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("")));
```